# submit form button SmartWizard

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to implement SmartWizard V6 code to submit/save form data to a mysql database. How can I configure the "Complete Order" button to be of type submit form and have an action to a .php page that executes the insertion of data into the database?

I have reviewed the .js files and I cannot find where I can configure this action. I'm new to programming and it may be something very simple but I can't locate or understand it. Thank you so much

Comment: I do not know this SmartWizard - but in general the type of the button is defined in html, not really in js, unless you add a button dynamically from code.